# Bulk insert. What is it really?

Tags: sql-server

I was doing some reading and research for some things I'm working on. I know what bulk inserts do and how to do them. Though i am at a block. Using sql triggers you can do some cool things on insert. But what happens on bulk insert. Mainly. does the bulk insert do something like this in plain context

```
Insert into table values('some value')--->sql triger
Insert into table values('some value')--->sql triger
Insert into table values('some value')--->sql triger
```

and so on. 
in which case, after every line a trigger for insert will fire off and sql will wait until thats done until the next line is reached.

I did a bit of reading here [on bulk inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702311/how-does-bulk-insert-work-internally) and found that it will always be better. But how does this affect triggers for insert? Apologies for any bad explanations or anything.

Answer (score 0):

As it is documented, triggers do not run on bulk insert.

But you can bulk insert into a temp table, then do a INSERT INTO SELECT FROM TEMP TABLE and you get all advantages on both - fast upload and triggers etc. running.

If you do C# then this also avoids the horrific locking code in the SqlBulkCopy class (on the table).

Comment: I like the simplicity with the work around and i really didnt understand what exactly happens. With the solution in hand i have another question which i will add to my question in a moment.

Comment: Another question you do not ADD, you ASK it - in a separate question. This one got an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, triggers on tables can execute either per row or per statement. The behaviour you are describing is characteristic of triggers that execute per row but SQL Server's flavour of SQL (called Transact-SQL) does not support them. There are only per-statement triggers in SQL Server.

In addition, if by "bulk insert" you mean the specific [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) statement of Transact-SQL, then what TomTom has said in his answer is almost true: triggers do not execute on BULK INSERT *by default*. You can specify that they do by adding the FIRE_TRIGGERS clause, and in that case each insert trigger will execute once per statement, as has already been explained.