# String Functions in SQL instead of C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2000000 sql records having names of customers. i want to changes as follows.

Sample Data :

```
Name
अमरीनaa मोयोद्दिनa शेखa
रऊफa वाहेदaa शेखa 
शहेदाबेगमaa रऊफaa शेखa
इम्रानa रउफ़aa शेखa 
दत्तुaa
कैलास धुमाळ
विलास दत्तु धुमाळ 
बिस्मिल्ला बी अ.हमीद खॉन
इस्माईल खॉन अ.हमीद खॉन 
नसरीन बेगम इस्माईल खान 
अ.हमिद खॉन इमाम खॉन
अजमेर खॉ इमाम खॉ
सुग्रा बी अजमेर खॉ
हनीफाबी अजमेर 
गौस अजमेर खान 
यासीन अजमेर खान 
राबिया बी मुश्ताक अली शेख
मो.सिंकंदर अली अन्वरअली शेख 
गफार मोयीन शेख 
नंदाबाई अशोक 
सचिन आशोक दिवेकर
सोनाजी नामदेव बोराडे
व्दारका राजू गायकवाड 
लिलाबाई सोनाजी बोराडे 
शारदाबाई राजू जगदाळे
अनिता अर्जुन जगदाळे
मंदा सुनील वाढेकर 
विठ्ठल दगडू 
सुनिल विश्वनाथ वाढेकर
शिवाजी विश्वनाथ
गयाबाई शिवाजी 
बाळू विश्वनाथ
वैशाली बाळू वाढेकर 
पांडुरंग नामदेब वाघ नामदेव 
हिराबाई पांडुरंग बाघ पांडुरंग 
सवीता संतोष किर्तीकर
चंद्रकला प्रल्हाद
संतोष प्रल्हाद
अनिल प्रल्हाद
विजय प्रल्हाद किर्तीकर 
राजेंद्र काशिनाथ 
हिराबाई राजेंद्र 
सुरेश पैठणे
नुतन सुरेश 
गौतम पैठणे
शारदा गौतम पैठणे गौतम
राजू अंबादास 
शोभाबाई राजू
सुनिता गोटीराम गायकवाड
बाळकृष्ण भानुदास दुलग
```

with above data having names with First, Middle and Last Names, I wants :

1. In every words of names aa should be replace with single a which is any where in name ( अमरीनaa will be अमरीन and रऊफaa will be रऊफ)
2. In every words of names a should be removed  which is in in last in word ( शेखa will be शेख and मोयोद्दिनa will be मोयोद्दिन)
3. If names have more then 2 words then last word will be in fisrt (विलास दत्तु धुमाळ will be धुमाळ विलास दत्तु)
4. If names have less then 3 words then it will be same as it is कैलास धुमाळ will कैलास धुमाळ and दत्तुaa will be दत्तुaa)
5. All Words staring and ending blank spaces should be removed.

for Above requirement i am using C# hard code to full fill but its takes 5 to 8 hours to complete, i want this should be done in sql side.

here my C# code :

```
 int _pcount = 0;
string _qr = "";
string _Name = "";
string _FinalName = "";
string _FNAME = "";
string _LastName = "";
string _MiddleName = "";
string _ID = "";
string[] _Split;
List<string> _a = new List<string>();
DataRowCollection _dr = _CDatabase._MGetDataRows("SELECT _ID, _FULLNAME FROM MYTABLE ORDER BY _FULLNAME"); // This is a function will execute a sql and return DataRowCollection
progressBar1.Maximum = _dr.Count + 1;
progressBar1.Value = 0;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MyConStr"))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (DataRow _row in _dr)
            {
                progressBar1.Value++;
                _pcount++;
                if (_pcount >= 100)
                {
                    _pcount = 0;
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
                _ID = _CConvert._MConvertToString(_row[0]);
                _Name = _CConvert._MConvertToString(_row[1]);

                _Split = _Name.Split(' ');
                _a = _Split.ToList();
                _a.Remove(" ");
                _a.Remove(" ");
                _a.Remove(" ");
                _a.Remove(" ");
                _a.Remove(" ");
                _a.Remove(" ");
                switch (_a.Count)
                {
                    case 0:
                        {
                            _FNAME = _FinalName = _Name;
                            _FNAME = _Name;
                            _LastName = "";
                            _MiddleName = "";
                            break;
                        }
                    case 1:
                        {
                            _FNAME = _FinalName = _Name;
                            _FNAME = "";
                            _LastName = _Name;
                            _MiddleName = "";
                            break;
                        }
                    case 2:
                        {
                            _FNAME = _FinalName = _Name;
                            _FNAME = _a[0];
                            _LastName = _FNAME;
                            _MiddleName = _a[1];
                            break;
                        }

                    case 3:
                        {
                            _FinalName = _a[2] + " " + _a[0] + " " + _a[1];
                            _FNAME = _a[0];
                            _MiddleName = _a[1];
                            _LastName = _a[2];
                            break;
                        }
                    case 4:
                        { // nasreen begum ismail khan
                            _FinalName = _a[3] + " " + _a[0] + " " + _a[1] + " " + _a[2];
                            _FNAME = _a[0] + " " + _a[1]; // nasreen begum
                            _MiddleName = _a[2];// ismail
                            _LastName = _a[3];//khan
                            break;
                        }

                    case 5:
                        { // jaibunnisa begum gulam dastagir sahab syed
                            _FinalName = _a[4] + " " + _a[0] + " " + _a[1] + " " + _a[2] + " " + _a[3];
                            _FNAME = _a[0] + " " + _a[1]; // jaibunnisa begum
                            _MiddleName = _a[2] + " " + _a[3];// gulam gastagir
                            _LastName = _a[4];//syed
                            break;
                        }

                    case 6:
                        { // jaibunnisa begum gulam dastagir syed
                            _FinalName = _a[5] + " " + _a[0] + " " + _a[1] + " " + _a[2] + " " + _a[3] + " " + _a[4];
                            _FNAME = _a[0] + " " + _a[1]; // jaibunnisa begum
                            _MiddleName = _a[2] + " " + _a[3] + " " + _a[4];// gulam gastagir
                            _LastName = _a[5];//syed
                            break;
                        }
                    case 7:
                        { // jaibunnisa begum gulam dastagir syed
                            _FinalName = _a[6] + " " + _a[0] + " " + _a[1] + " " + _a[2] + " " + _a[3] + " " + _a[4] + " " + _a[5];
                            _FNAME = _a[0] + " " + _a[1]; // jaibunnisa begum
                            _MiddleName = _a[2] + " " + _a[3] + " " + _a[4] + " " + _a[5];// gulam gastagir
                            _LastName = _a[6];//syed
                            break;
                        }
                    default:
                        {
                            _FinalName = _Name;
                            _FNAME = "";
                            _LastName = "";
                            _MiddleName = "";
                            break;
                        }
                }

                _qr = "UPDATE MYTABLE SET _FULLNAME = N'" + _FinalName + "' WHERE _ID = '" + _ID + "'";
                _mExcute(_qr, con, trans);
            }
            trans.Commit();
            con.Close();
            trans.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("DONE");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            con.Close();
            _CShowMessageBox._MShowErrorMessageBox(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"but its takes 5 to 8 hours to complete, i want this should be done in sql side."* - Sound like you want it to be fast, and assuming it will be faster in SQL. So, would you prefer a fast C# solution over a slow SQL solution, or does it actually need to be SQL?

Comment: Something in your code doesn't make sense. This line _Name.Trim().Replace(" ", "");_ is supposed to remove spaces but it doesn't work at all because you need to reassing the return value of Replace to the _Name variable. Then you try to split on spaces (that you should have removed at the line before, finally the Remove call don't do anything for the same reason of the replace. Perhaps you need to debug a bit this code before searching how to get better performances.

Comment: @GolezTrol SQL will be fast as compare to c# due to in c# i am using foreach loop which is taking time. as well as in last i am updating a record also so  its a other reason also of taking time.

Comment: Did you profile it? I would add some counters or just some `Stopwatch` instances and figure out where it is slow and then optimize based on that. Also you could use a parrallel foreach to multi-thread this instead of executing each record sequentially. Finally use a sql parameter instead of string concatination, this will prevent possible errors if someone has a `'` in their name. It would really suck to get a sql error on item number 1,999,999 and have the transaction roll back.

Comment: Also it would be more efficient if you used a DataReader when reading the names from the table instead of reading everything into memory at once. Use 2 connections, one for the reader and one for the update commands. Be sure to close the reader and corresponding connection before you commit the transaction.

Comment: @Steve thanks for pointing this line Name.Trim().Replace(" ", ""), in original code its dont have, I Updated question

Comment: @Igor _CDatabase._MGetDataRows contains SqlDataAdapter .. this function execute sql and return DataRowCollection

Comment: @Igor also using to connections, 1 in _CDatabase._MGetDataRows and it will be colsed after returning DataRowCollection and 2nd connection is using for updating record

Comment: @ImranAliKhan - Yes but, correct me if I am wrong, this row collection gets filled up front with all of your 2,000,000 records. If you use a DataReader the record is pulled over only when you ask for it / iterate over it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not even a question.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy, its a question and its related to programming tooo.

Comment: A question is a sentence ending with the question mark. There is not a single question mark in your post. I don't know what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create two functions:

```
-- Splits the name parts
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)

-- Formats the name
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FormatName]
( 
    @Name NVARCHAR(200)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CountNameParts AS INT
    DECLARE @FirstName AS NVARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @MiddleName AS NVARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @LastName AS NVARCHAR(200)

    SET @CountNameParts = 0
    SET @FirstName = ''
    SET @MiddleName = ''
    SET @LastName = ''

    DECLARE @UserName TABLE(
        Id INT NOT NULL,
        DATA NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
    )

    --5.All Words staring and ending blank spaces should be removed.
    INSERT INTO @UserName
    SELECT ID, Data
    from dbo.Split(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Name)), ' ')

    SELECT @CountNameParts=count(*) from @UserName
    IF @CountNameParts = 3
    BEGIN
        SELECT @LastName=Data from @UserName where Id = 3
        SELECT @MiddleName=Data from @UserName where Id = 2
        SELECT @FirstName=Data from @UserName where Id = 1
    END
    ELSE IF @CountNameParts = 2
    BEGIN
        SELECT @LastName=Data from @UserName where Id = 2
        SELECT @FirstName=Data from @UserName where Id = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @FirstName=Data from @UserName where Id = 1
    END

    --2.In every words of names a should be removed which is in in last in word ( शेखa will be शेख and मोयोद्दिनa will be मोयोद्दिन)
    SELECT @LastName=REPLACE(@LastName, 'a', '')

    --1.In every words of names aa should be replace with single a which is any where in name ( अमरीनaa will be अमरीन and रऊफaa will be रऊफ)
    SELECT @FirstName=REPLACE(@FirstName, 'aa', 'a')
    SELECT @MiddleName=REPLACE(@MiddleName, 'aa', 'a')
    SELECT @LastName=REPLACE(@LastName, 'aa', 'a')

    --3.If names have more then 2 words then last word will be in fisrt (विलास दत्तु धुमाळ will be धुमाळ विलास दत्तु)
    IF @CountNameParts = 2
    BEGIN
        SET @MiddleName=@FirstName
        SET @FirstName=@LastName
        SET @LastName=@MiddleName
        SET @MiddleName=''
    END

    --4.If names have less then 3 words then it will be same as it is कैलास धुमाळ will कैलास धुमाळ and दत्तुaa will be दत्तुaa)

    RETURN @FirstName + ' ' + @MiddleName + ' ' + @LastName
END
```

Then just do a massive update like so:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET _FULLNAME = [dbo].[FormatName](_FULLNAME)
```

Comment: SELECT @LastName=REPLACE(@LastName, 'a', '') will be removed all a from @LastName, need only remove last a of a word (Imrana Alia Khana will be Imran Ali Khan)

Comment: I've already provided the basic functionality. You can edit the business rules to whatever you need...

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear for me if your strings processing can easily be implemented in SQL, but in order to be faster it must allow set based approach. Something like:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET _FULLNAME = dbo.getFullName(paramters)
```

The main cause for your code being slow is the huge number of UPDATE statements. If you use SQL Profiler, you will see how much activity you generate.

Before trying to convert to SQL, I would try the following:

1) Precompute your full name into a list of strings
2) Create a buffer table with a structure like the following (Buffer):

```
ID INT NOT NULL,
FullName NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
```

3) Use [Bulk Insert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nikhilsi/2008/06/11/bulk-insert-into-sql-from-c-app/) to persist to Buffer. [Bulk insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702311/how-does-bulk-insert-work-internally) is much faster (dozens, if not hundreads of times faster) as it mimimizes round trips between your application and SQL Server.

4) Use a statement to update from your buffer to your final table

```
UPDATE Dest
SET T.FullName = B.FullName
FROM MYTABLE T
JOIN Buffer B ON B.ID = T.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write SQL CLR function in C# language.
You can use this function in your SQL statement and comlete task in one update!

```
[SqlFunction()]
public static SqlDouble addTax(SqlDouble originalAmount)
{
    < here is your code in C# (you already done this part!)>
}
```

Article how to deploy this:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/sql-clr-for-beginner-part-3-create-function-in-sql-clr/